# Excluir registro usando NGRX e effects

Tags: angular

Estou estudando gerenciamento de estados e ao tentar excluir um registro ao bater no meu endpoint, o valor do id esta indo "undefined".

**Component**

```
this.store.dispatch(DELETE_COMANDA(comandaId));
```

**Actions:**

```
export const DELETE_COMANDA = createAction('[Comandas] Delete Comandas', props <{ payload:number }>());
export const DELETE_COMANDA_SUCESS = createAction('[Comandas] Delete comandas SUCESS', props <{ payload }>());
export const DELETE_COMANDA_FAIL = createAction('[Comandas] Delete comandas FAIL', props<Error>());
```

**reducers**

```
  on(comandasActions.DELETE_COMANDA_SUCESS, (state,  { payload } ) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      payload
    };
  }),

  on(comandasActions.DELETE_COMANDA_FAIL, (state, error) => ({ ...state, error})),
```

**effect**

```
  deleteComanda$: Observable<any> = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(comandasActions.DELETE_COMANDA),
    map((action) => action.payload),
    mergeMap((id) =>
      this.comandaService.deleteComanda(id).pipe(
        map((payload) => comandasActions.DELETE_COMANDA_SUCESS({payload})),
        catchError((error) => of(comandasActions.DELETE_COMANDA_FAIL(error)))
        ))
    )
  );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que seu efeito esta esperando um objeto com a propiedade payload e vc ta mandando uma chamada comandaId

Tenta assim:

```
this.store.dispatch(DELETE_COMANDA({payload: comandaId}));
```